# How to read logs from the iOS devices using Objective C os_log API?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I want to collect device logs from the iOS device to the server remotely. Earlier I used the ASL search API's to query the logs from the device. Since the ASL library is depreciated, how can we get the logs using OS_log API (Objective-C)?